# Mysql using an "as" for more calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

Say i have the following `SQL` statment:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(UHAM.module_id)    AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete = 1
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END)     AS complete,
  (total / complete * 100) AS percentage,
  AT.name
FROM user_has_academy_module UHAM
  JOIN academy_team AT ON AT.id = UHAM.academy_team_id
WHERE academy_team_id IN (317, 305)
GROUP BY UHAM.academy_team_id;
```

As you can see ive used `total` and `complete` to try and calculate a new value. However this cannot be done as my script says: `unknown column total`

So my question is: is there a way to do the above or do i need to write the same `count`statement again (making the sql kinda messy)

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. (Will not execute on newer MySQL versions. Will return arbitrary data using older MySQL versions.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with another select :

```
SELECT t.*,
        (total / complete * 100) AS percentage
FROM(
    SELECT
      COUNT(UHAM.module_id)    AS total,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete = 1
        THEN 1
            ELSE NULL END)     AS complete,
      AT.name
    FROM user_has_academy_module UHAM
      JOIN academy_team AT ON AT.id = UHAM.academy_team_id
    WHERE academy_team_id IN (317, 305)
    GROUP BY UHAM.academy_team_id) t
```

You can't use an alias on the same level it was created, you either have to copy the whole expression again, or wrap it with another select like the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will either have to use the entire expression for both `count` operation (OR) get it done in a outer query like

```
SELECT *, (total / complete * 100) AS percentage FROM (
SELECT
  COUNT(UHAM.module_id)    AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete = 1
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END)     AS complete,
  AT.name
FROM user_has_academy_module UHAM
  JOIN academy_team AT ON AT.id = UHAM.academy_team_id
WHERE academy_team_id IN (317, 305)
GROUP BY UHAM.academy_team_id ) XXX;
```

(OR)

```
  COUNT(UHAM.module_id)    AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete = 1
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END)     AS complete,
  (COUNT(UHAM.module_id) / COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END) * 100) AS percentage,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*,(total / complete * 100) AS percentage
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(UHAM.module_id)    AS total, COUNT(CASE WHEN UHAM.is_complete =              
1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)     AS complete FROM user_has_academy_module UHAM
JOIN academy_team AT ON AT.id = UHAM.academy_team_id
WHERE academy_team_id IN (317, 305)
GROUP BY UHAM.academy_team_id
)A
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to approach this is to use a subquery.  However, that is rather inefficient in MySQL, because the subquery is materialized -- and that incurs extra overhead when running the query.

I would suggest writing the logic as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
       SUM(UHAM.is_complete = 1) as complete,
       AVG(UHAM.is_complete = 1) as percentage
       AT.name
. . .
```

This uses the fact that MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

This version makes the assumption that `is_complete` does not take on `NULL` values (including that logic would be pretty simple).